# Should we consolidate the history and etymology tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking through the questions for [history](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) and [etymology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) tags, and it seems like there is a significant amount of overlap between the two.  Should these be consolidated, or are they different enough to remain separate?

Answer (score 7):

Not all history questions could be tagged with etymology, for example this one: [Why were ゐ and ゑ eliminated?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/88/why-were-and-eliminated)  Let's keep both of them, but try to standardize on using "etymology" instead of "history" when the question is about a word's etymology.

Comment: I agree, and in particular [history] should not be a tag synonym for [etymology].  The other direction may make sense.

Answer (score -1):

My vote would be to have them used as synonyms as not all people know the word etymology.

Comment: That was kind of my worry too.  People tracking etymology won't see all of the etymology questions because some of them will be tagged as history or something else, so we might be getting ourselves into a long-term retagging process.