# Word-origin & etymology tags, consolidate? synonymate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

There seems to be some posts with the tag [word-origin](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-origin) that i think should be either change to [etymology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) or made synonyms of etymology.

This question is slightly related to [Should we consolidate the history and etymology tags?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114/should-we-consolidate-the-history-and-etymology-tags) but figured before i should check with everyone what the best course of action may be.

I don't think most people know the word etymology, and thus we'll continue to see tags like "word-origins" and "origins" pop-up over time.  For this reason, I am in favor of making them synonyms as opposed to deleting the tag "word-origin"

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: I'll admit I didn't know the word "etymology" until I started seeing it on this site.

Comment: Yep, making them synonyms sounds good.

Comment: since i lack the rep to make a synonym, can someone do this for me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make `word-origin` a synonym of `etymology`, which is broader, but not in a way useful for our purposes.

I would leave `history` separate though.

Comment: yeah, i'm fine will history being seperate, per the conversation in the other thread.